# django {% trans "Hello" %} isnot working

Tags: python, django

I know, this thing was asked like trillion times, but i cannot still get my django templates translated.

I created `locale` folder in project tree.

I added in settings.py

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'locale'),
)
```

settings.py default language is English:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
```

I added more languages like:

```
LANGUAGES = ( 
  ('de', _('German')),
  ('fr', _('French')),
  ('es', _('Spanish')),
  ('pt', _('Portuguese'))
)
```

and added into `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

```
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
```

and into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

**NOW**: I added this to my index.html

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "it is me" as me %}
<title>Newsportal {{ me }}</title>
```

and did:

```
python manage.py makemessages -a
```

and translated `"it is me"` into `"das bin ich"` (it is german) and did

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

it created .mo file. everything looks fantastic

and I changed the language of my chrome browser to german.

**BUT**: it still shows the text as `"it is me"`.

what am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**: first of all, thanks to Liarez for standing by me during this horrible time, I finally found my mistake.

I was doing:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
   os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale'),
)
```

which went one step deeper in project tree where there are settings.py.

i changed this to

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
   os.path.realpath('locale'),
)
```

and it is working like in fairy tales.

Comment: Check if there is no other "it is me". Try to change language in that view with `translation.activate("de")`.

Comment: @matousc you mean inside .po file?

Comment: Wich is your actual language ? "it is me" is English words, did you change your language ? using `translation.activate("de")` ? You can check your language in the template using `{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}, so you can check if translation are working

Comment: @Liarez oh no, i didnot. where do I do it? in settings.py?

Comment: You need a view to detect the language changes, something like `www.yourproject.com/de`, this should call a view that detects the language you want to change and then change it. I can show you a simple function if you need

Comment: @Liarez yes in .po file. I have got same problem, there were two same strings.

Comment: Can you show that "same" strings ? Edit your post, I'll make an answer about easy way to manage language changes, but you can open a console with `manage.py shell` and make some tests there

Comment: @Liarez hey guys, i am the one who asked the question haha. i checked .po file, there is only one "it is me"

Comment: How did you translate the message? Thats not the point, but you also need to add `en-us` to your languages

Comment: @cor i translated by hand inside .po file.

Comment: So I guess you have edited the `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` file, and appended `msgid "it is me" msgstr "das bin ich"` to that file. And after that you have executed the command `python manage.py compilemessages`

Comment: @cor exactly. and it created the .mo file as well

Comment: Check the accepted languages header sent by browser, it set all my request to default to english regardless cookie value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to manage languages, and change active language via URL:

in the urls.py add:

```
url(r'^set_language/(?P<language_code>[\w-]+)/?', 'YOUR_PROJECT.views.set_language', name='set_language'),
```

---

In your views.py:

```
def set_language(request, language_code):
    ''' Change language '''

    translation.activate(language_code)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

---

In any template:

You should ask (just for testing) in any place of your template: `{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}` to know wich is the actual language and check if translations are working

Comment: thanks, but i did this in my view. still "it is me". i did in views ``translation.activate('de')``

Comment: When you add `{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}` in the template, Does it show `de` or `en` ?

Comment: inside template ``LANGUAGE_CODE`` is giving me ``de``. but why is the string still in english?

Comment: Let's talk in [this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60813/django-tests) to avoid commenting all the time

Comment: I found the issue: the ``PROJECT_PATH`` was one step deeper where settings.py is. so it looked for ``locale`` folder in folder where settings.py is which is wrong. I had to write this: ``LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.realpath('locale'),
)`` and it worked like in fairy tales

Comment: Nice to hear you finally found the issue!